# Add option should take string (which has white spaces) from command line with out specifying ' ' or " "

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a python script which I am running from command line. Python script takes string as argument and save in database. But I dont want to specify "" or '' in my command arguments.

Experts some suggestion please ?

```
class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, type, participant, text=''):
            self.type = type
            self.participant = participant
            self.text = text


def getOptions():
    global parser
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--child", action="store_true", dest="child",      default=False, help=SUPPRESS_HELP)

    parser.add_option("-s", "--type", dest="type")
    parser.add_option("-b", "--participant", dest="participant")
    parser.add_option("-t", "--text", dest="text")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    return options
```

I run script like
myScript.py -t "This is text" --> **In database it saved as This is text**
but when I run like this 
myScript.py -t This is text --> **In database it saved as This**
I want to specify string with using double quotes ("") or single quotes('')

Comment: This is a shell issue, not a programming issue. In order for the shell to know to pass a whole phrase with spaces into your script as one argument, it has to be enclosed in quotes of some sort.

Comment: @glibdud, is regex work here ?

Comment: The separating of the command line into a list of arguments happens before your script is even invoked. The only way I can think of that you could do this would be to grab all command line args with `sys.argv` and parse it yourself (without argparse).

Comment: @glibdud, can you please give me some refrence on how to do this, I am new to python

Comment: Not really any more than you could get from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

Comment: Did you try escaping spaces? Like ``myScript.py -t This\ is\ text``? Just curious if that works.

Comment: I've seen this done, at a code dojo. The approach involved subclassing `iterator`. If you are new to Python then that is not a recommendable line of approach. If something as simple as parsing command line arguments involves subclassing `iterator` then the problem is with the spec and not the code.

Comment: You can specify `nargs='+'` for the `-t` option, but that might cause more problems than it solves. Learn to work *with* your shell rather than trying to work *against* it.